# jQuery plugin template chainability with each and ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, each, ready, chainability

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, and I want to attach that plugin to the **selected element only** when it is present, **without** having any click or other events.

This plugin has it other chained functions and I want to call this functions when this plugin is attached to that element.

And I want to **pass that element as an object** into the chained functions.

But I get this error message and the plugin does not work of course! I get the same error whether I use `each` or `ready` in that plugin

```
return this.each(function() {...}

return this.ready(function() {...)
```

> TypeError: $this.function_1 is not a function

How do I make it right?

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.box').selection();

    });


    (function($){

        $.fn.extend({ 

            selection: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    element:    "selection"
                }

                var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
                var o = options;

                // Must declare a this variable outside the core if you have other children functions inside this plugin.
                var $this = this;

                return this.each(function() {

                    // Set the object.
                    var object = $(this);
                    //alert(object.html());

                    // Attach the functions.
                    $this.function_1(object);
                    $this.function_2(object);


                });

                // function_1
                $this.function_1 = function(object)
                {
                    alert('function 1');

                }

                // function_2
                $this.function_2 = function(object)
                {
                    alert('function 2');
                }

            }
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

html,

```
<div class="box">

    <ul class="selection">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwDwU/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `return` before declaring the functions. Move the function declarations above the call to `return` and it works.